# Stuck on proving a variation of the Central Limit Theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I'm trying to prove the following version of the central limit theorem.

Let $$L^n = (L_1^n,...L_n^n) $$

such that the $L_i$ are i.i.d.,

there exists a sequence of constants such that $|L_i^n|\leq K^n$ for all $i$ and $K^n \rightarrow{0}$,

and it holds that for $Z_n= \sum_{i=1}^nL_i^n$ we have $\mathbb{E}[Z_n] \rightarrow{\mu}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Z_n) \rightarrow \sigma^2$.

Then we have that $Z_n$ converges in distribution to $Z$ where $Z$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I think it should be done with Characteristic functions + Levy's continuity theorem. The characterstic function will factor by the first hypothesis but I don't see how to incorporate the other two to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: Are the superscrpts $n$ a power or notation indicating an index?

Comment: Where is this version from?

Comment: @WilliamM. they indicate an index, it is also called the CLT for triangular schemes, and it is used in mathematical finance.

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Just to clarify: are you looking for a proof of the CLT for triangular arrays which uses characteristic functions?

Comment: Yes I think so, but I'm not familiar with the term triangular array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the argument uses Levy's Convergence theorem and is like the proof for CLT in the iid case.

Let $\mu_n = \mathbb{E}\left[L^n_1\right]$ and $\sigma_n^2 = \text{Var}\left(L^n_1\right)$, then by the assumptions on $Z$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Z_n\right] = n \mu_n \to \mu \quad \text{ and } \quad \text{Var}\left(Z_n\right) = n \sigma_n \to \sigma, \qquad (*)$$
which implies that $\mu_n = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\sigma^2_n = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

In a similar spirit to estimates derived in the proof of the standard CLT (see for example section 18.3 of D. Williams's *Probability with Martingales*), let $R_2(x) = e^{ix} - \left(1 + ix - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ be the remainder of second order Taylor approximation of $e^{ix}$. Additionally, it holds that $\left|R_2(x)\right| \leq \frac{|x|^3}{6}$, see the Williams's book if it isn't clear to you why this is true. Then we have for the characteristic function of $L_1^n - \mu_n$, the following estimate,
$$\varphi_{L_1^n - \mu_n}\left(\theta\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp{\left(i\theta \left(L_1^n - \mu_n\right)\right)}\right] = 1 - \frac{\theta^2\sigma_n^2}{2} + \mathbb{E}\left[R_2\left(\theta L_1^n\right)\right] = 1 - \frac{\theta^2\sigma_n^2}{2} + R^n\left(\theta\right),$$
where $\left|R^n\left(\theta\right)\right| \leq \frac{\left|\theta\right|^3}{6}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|L_1^n - \mu_n\right|^3\right]$. Applying Hölder and the bound on $L_1^n$, we have
$$\left|R^n\left(\theta\right)\right| \leq \left\|L_1^n - \mu_n\right\|_\infty\mathbb{E}\left[\left(L_1^n - \mu_n\right)^2\right]\leq \frac{\left|\theta\right|^3}{6}\left(K_n + \left|\mu_n\right|\right)\mathbb{E}\left[\left(L_1^n - \mu_n\right)^2\right] = \frac{\left|\theta\right|^3}{6}\left(K_n + \left|\mu_n\right|\right) \sigma_n^2,$$
here $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the sup-norm.
The above implies that $R^n = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ as $K_n, \left|\mu_n\right| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and $\sigma^2_n = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Denote by $\varphi_{Z_n}$ the characteristic function of $Z_n$, which is given by
$$\varphi_{Z_n}\left(\theta\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp{\left(i\theta Z_n\right)}\right] = \prod_{i = 1}^n\varphi_{L_i^n} =  e^{i\theta \mu_n n}\left(\varphi_{L_1^n - \mu_n}\left(\theta\right)\right)^n. $$
Taking logs and applying the asymptotics we derived and $(*)$, we get
\begin{gather}
\log{\varphi_{Z_n}\left(\theta\right)}  
= i\theta \mu_n n + n\log{\left(1 - \frac{\theta^2 \sigma_n^2}{2} + R_n\left(\theta\right)\right)} \\
= i\theta \mu_n n - \frac{\theta^2\sigma_n^2 n}{2} + n R_n\left(\theta\right) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} i\theta \mu - \frac{\theta^2\sigma^2}{2},
\end{gather}
as $nR_n\left(\theta\right) \to 0$. Finally Levy's Convergence theorem lets us conclude that $Z_n$ converges weakly to $Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma\right)$.

Comment: Why does $nR_n(\theta) \rightarrow{0}$ since $R_n = O(1/n)$? We can only conclude $nR_n(\theta) \rightarrow C$ right?

Comment: $R_n = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ exactly means that $nR_n \to 0$, see [Little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).